# insert value and click button on anotger website

Tags: click

I have a website(1) but I can insert a 1 value in textbox and submit it, and I have 1500 value to insert

So I need to make an other Website(2) have the 1500 values in a table, and insert these values in website(1)
From website(2)by login and insert value and click on submit button in website(1)

Comment: Can you make demo in JSFiddle?

Comment: Simple Question... Why not make website one call the Database of website two and insert the data then website two has the data to display.